# How to add more than one parameter in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to add more than one parameter in my report.

In Database Expert --> Modify Command I've try execute this and it works

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_rpt_pbos9003]{?scn}
```

but when i added the second parameter

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_rpt_pbos9003]('{?scn}','{?move}');
```

it won't work.

I've check my stored procedure and it return result.

Does anyone know what is the error?

Comment: CR doesn't throw any error?

Comment: You can have a parameter in Database Expert like you are doing, or create a client side parameter under Field Explorer > Parameter Fields. Using Database Expert changes the SQL you send to the database, but is harder to use for end-users.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

> EXEC [dbo].[sp_rpt_pbos9003] '{?scn}','{?move}'

Or

> EXEC [dbo].[sp_rpt_pbos9003] '{?scn}','{?move}';

It's the same